# how can I call a function of class to fetch data in .php file from angularjs code?

Tags: php, angularjs

I am new to angularjs and php. Right now, I am working on small dynamic website. I just want to know, is **there any particular service in angularjs, to call a function written in php file to get/fetch data from database?** 
Because, I don't want to *transfer variable from angularjs and check its value in php.*

Comment: No there's no magic shortcut to have js (angular) code call php code directly.

Comment: Rememder that Javascript (Angular) is a client-side language (runs in the browser)  whereas PHP is a server-side language. Anytime you fetch from  javascript via an ajax request you are fetching data from a server which in your case is running PHP.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. **Yoshi** and **Jamie_D** -Sahil Mujawar